# focus() doesn't working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, focus

I tried to use focus() in IE, but it's not working.

This is my source code.

----------------------------HTML----------------------------

```
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="INPUT_TEST_1" onblur="fn_onblur(this)"/>
    <input type="text" id="INPUT_TEST_2" onblur="fn_onblur(this)"/>
</td>
```

----------------------------JavaScript----------------------------

```
function fn_onblur(obj){
var id = obj.id;
var target = $("#"+id);
if(gfn_isNull(target.val())){
    alert(id+" need input value!!!");
    target.focus();
    setTimeout(function() { 
        obj.focus();
    }, 1);
    return;
}
```

}

The problem is that when I click INPUT_TEST_1 and INPUT_TEST_2 without any value,

focus() doesn't working, but this works in Chrome and FF.

I already tried

```
setTimeout(function(){obj.focus();},1);
setTimeout(function(){target.focus();},1);
setTimeout(function(){$("#"+id).focus();},1);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(id).focus();},1);
```

And etc.

However, anything didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you sure it's `focus()` not working, or that `gfn_isNull(target.val())` is returning `false` in IE?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan yes. gfn_isNull is returning 'false' and I am sure focus() is not working since I already tested many times on Chrome and FF. Only IE gives this problem

Comment: If `gfn_isNull(target.val())` is returning false, then your `if` statement isn't being hit. You need to find out why `false` is being returned when it should not be. `focus` is not the issue.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - Sorry, it's my mistake. gfn_isNull is returning true if input is empty and is returning false. This means this function has no error.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to overcome by setting a timeout to focus into the input

```
<form>
   <label for="name">Name</label>
   <input id="name" name="name" />
    <br />
   <label for="city">City</label>
   <input id="city" name="city" />
    <br />
</form>
```

Then ..

```
$('input[name="name"]').blur(function(e){
    if(/^\s*$/.test($(this).val())){
        alert('Value needed');
        setTimeout(function() {e.target.focus();}, 50);
    }
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/6dmvh/)

Comment: This works when one of input is not empty. However, if every input is empty, this shows repeated alert. The only thing that I can do is just kill the IE process.

Answer (score 0):

Last year I had some problem with onblur Html-attribute on IE.. I found that it only works when tabindex attribute is set.

If you read on MSDN, it's said.

NB: i don't know if IE10 and IE11 have still got the problem.. and we don't know on which version of IE you are working on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: IE 7~9 gives this error. I am not yet test IE10 and 11 since this have to work on IE 7~9.